# How do I reverse a number in javascript using a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, binary

For a project, I am supposed to write a function in javascript that takes a value and converts it to binary (from decimal) and I need a step to be able to reverse the digits of a number (for the remainders) and I am unsure of how to do it, within the restrictions of using a loop.

(if theres any questions to explain my question, please let me know)

Comment: Please give a few examples of your required input and output

Comment: I don't see any need for a loop in the task ..? Please see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score 0):

Try this method ,

```js
function DecToBinWithRev(num) {
  let result = Number(num).toString(2).split('').reverse().join('')
  return result
}


console.log(DecToBinWithRev(10))
```

Comment: It looks like they just need to convert a decimal to binary, not actually reverse a number. Please refrain answering homework questions for which OP hasn't shown any attempt to resolve the task.

Comment: maybe i am misunderstanding their question.

Comment: @Dazil - you're misunderstanding the fact that the OP posted just an assignment, showing no work and having no specific programming question, and expecting the community to solve if for them. Please don't do this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Right O.

Answer (score 0):

I m not sure if this will work or not..

```
var splitString = str.split(“”);
var revArray = splitString.reverse();
var joinArray = revArray.join(“”);
```

if u want to loop it over loop it with splitString.length & then followed by remainder logic inside loop

Comment: Looks like you're solving someone's assignment, with them doing no work at all, aside from posting the assignment and asking the Community to take care of it. Please don't do this.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out

```
  let number = 1234567890; // your number
  let output = []; // to save output value

  // makes your number into string and then convert it into an array
  number = number.toString().split('');

  // here the maximum itreation count of array is the length of the array
  for (let i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {

      // creating an array of numbers in reverse order
      output[i] = number[number.length - (i + 1)];

  };

  // joining the array of reversed array and converting back to numbers
  output = Number(output.join(""));

  console.log(output); // here is your reversed number
```

**Lets see how it works**

**Creating variables**

First take we create a number and assign it to 'number' variable. Then we create an empty array to store the output value(reversed number).

**Converting**

we are assigning new value to number variable After changing the data type of number to string because we can't use split method to a number.
The split method split each character by the condition we pass in the split method itself and return an array. In which each index of array contain each of spited sting chunks.
Then finally the returned array is assigned to the number variable.

Remember the number is now an array.

**Reversing**

This is the part where for loop comes in. We loop through to all of the number array elements and add the values of the number array in reverse order to the output array.

**Creating numbers form array**

Here we want to convert the array back to number, How do we do that ?
we need to first join the array using join method. Then convert the joined string to a number.
By passing a sting which only contains a valid number to the 'Number()' as argument the 'Number' method create a number form the string we pass.
Then we assign the converted Number to output variable.
Note : you don't have to worry about data type in java scripts when we assign new thing to a normal variable.
So the output become a number from array.

So the answer is in the output variable.

Comment: Looks like you're solving someone's assignment, with them doing no work at all, aside from posting the assignment and asking the Community to take care of it. Please don't do this.

Comment: Also: please don't tell someone that something is "very simple" - especially for a beginner, this might be far from simple (simple to "you" doesn't equate to simple to "everyone")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).